# Modify eachline characters between two patterns

Tags: shell, file, vim, sed

I need to modify the certain characters between two patterns in each line.

Eample:: (File content saved as myfile.txt)

```
abc, def, 1, {,jsdfsd,kfgdsf,lgfgd}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {,jsdfsqwe,k,fdfsfl}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {,asdasdj,kgfdgdf,ldsfsdf}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {,jsds,kfdsf,fdsl}, 2, pqr, stu
```

I want to edit & save myfile.txt like mentioned below

```
abc, def, 1, {jsdfsd kfgdsf lgfgd}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {jsdfsqwe k fdfsfl}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {asdasdj kgfdgdf ldsfsdf}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {jsds kfdsf fdsl}, 2, pqr, stu
```

I've used following command to edit & save myfile.txt

```
sed '/1,/,/,2/{/1,/n;/,2/!{s/,/ /g}}' myfile.txt
```

This command did not helped me to achive my goal. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: `/1,/,/,2/` syntax is for multiple line matching, not same line

Comment: please explain on what rules your changes should occur.. for given ip/op, `sed 's/,/ /6; s/,/ /5; s/,//4'` would work.. but would it work for your real use case?

Answer (score 3):

**`awk`** would be more suitable in such case:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=", " }{ gsub(/,/, " ", $4); sub(/\{ /, "{", $4) }1' file
```

The output:

```
abc, def, 1, {jsdfsd kfgdsf lgfgd}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {jsdfsqwe k fdfsfl}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {asdasdj kgfdgdf ldsfsdf}, 2, pqr, stu
abc, def, 1, {jsds kfdsf fdsl}, 2, pqr, stu
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you also have the tag `vim`, you can do it in vim via:

`:%normal 0f{vi{:s/\%V,/ /g^M`

Where the last two characters are actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: The first comma should be deleted. Have a look at my vim solution below.

Answer (score 1):

In vim there is also the possibility of lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
%s/\v(\{.*)@<=,(.*})@=/ /g
```

Matches every `,` between a `{` and a `}` and replaces them with a space.

if it is the case, that a `,` directly afer a `{` should be deleted, not replaced with a space, it is possible to run this line in a slightly modified version first:

```
%s/\v(\{)@<=,(.*})@=/ /g
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a sub-replace-expression in your `:substitute` command.

```
:%s/{\zs[^}]*\ze}/\=substitute(submatch(0)[1:], ',', ' ', 'g')
```

This matches in between your curly braces and then replaces each `,` with a space while avoiding the first comma.

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h /\zs
:h submatch()
:h sublist
:h substitute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'match($0,/{.*}/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/,/," ",val);gsub(/{ /,"{",val);gsub(/} /,"}",val);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);next} 1'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
match($0,/{.*}/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  gsub(/,/," ",val);
  gsub(/{ /,"{",val);
  gsub(/} /,"}",val);
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vim:

```
:%normal! 4f,xf,r f,r 

: ........... command mode
% ........... in the whole file
normal! ..... normal mode
4f, ......... jump inside { block
x ........... delete the first comma
f, .......... jump to the next comma
r<Space> .... replace comma with space
```

Comment: `4f,` jumps inside of the `{` block because there are exactly 3 commas before the `{` and one inside. What I proposed was to actually find the first `{` character. Maybe both solutions work in their own way, but if you want to explain how it works, `jump inside { block` is a bit misleading. (Another approach is to not explain anything :-P )

Answer (score 0):

Some more awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub(/,/," ",$1); $0=RS $0}1' FS=} OFS=} RS={ ORS= file
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/,/, " ", $2); $2="{" $2 "}"}1' FS='[{}]' OFS= file
```